# How do people decide what hashtags to use in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Without using paid-for 3rd party tools, I don't see how to insert a hashtag without just guessing! Searching about how to use hashtags just produces shallow, ambiguous pages that are just cheap content for ad clicks. #(hash?)TagsSeemStupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a hashtag, think of some examples that could fit in your case. For example, if you want to post a picture of a cute cat, think of maybe #cutecats #catpictures etc. Enter the hashtag in the searchbox an you will also see a few suggestions. Search for the hashtag and you will see other posts that use that hashtag. If this fits your audience, use it. Another way is to look at the popular hashtags in the sidebar.